# Tailwind/ CSS image should not be shown outside container

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I am still struggling to find a solution for my problem.

Only the parts of the icon should be visible which are within the top div container. The parts of the icon that are outside of the top div container should not been shown or should be hidden.

https://play.tailwindcss.com/XyuTtdKbxV

Thx
-Dave

```
<div class="rounded rounded-xl w-72 h-32 bg-red-700 relative block">
    <div class="w-36 h-36 text-red-800 absolute -left-8 -bottom-8">
        <svg fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512"><!-- Font Awesome Free 5.15.3 by @fontawesome  - https://fontawesome.com License - https://fontawesome.com/license/free (Icons: CC BY 4.0, Fonts: SIL OFL 1.1, Code: MIT License) --><path d="M483.55,227.55H462c-50.68,0-76.07-61.27-40.23-97.11L437,115.19A28.44,28.44,0,0,0,396.8,75L381.56,90.22c-35.84,35.83-97.11,10.45-97.11-40.23V28.44a28.45,28.45,0,0,0-56.9,0V50c0,50.68-61.27,76.06-97.11,40.23L115.2,75A28.44,28.44,0,0,0,75,115.19l15.25,15.25c35.84,35.84,10.45,97.11-40.23,97.11H28.45a28.45,28.45,0,1,0,0,56.89H50c50.68,0,76.07,61.28,40.23,97.12L75,396.8A28.45,28.45,0,0,0,115.2,437l15.24-15.25c35.84-35.84,97.11-10.45,97.11,40.23v21.54a28.45,28.45,0,0,0,56.9,0V462c0-50.68,61.27-76.07,97.11-40.23L396.8,437A28.45,28.45,0,0,0,437,396.8l-15.25-15.24c-35.84-35.84-10.45-97.12,40.23-97.12h21.54a28.45,28.45,0,1,0,0-56.89ZM224,272a48,48,0,1,1,48-48A48,48,0,0,1,224,272Zm80,56a24,24,0,1,1,24-24A24,24,0,0,1,304,328Z"/></svg>
    </div>
<div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're tagging Tailwind, you can utilize the overflow class with hidden. I.e. `overflow-hidden` on the parent container.

Tailwind play link, [here](https://play.tailwindcss.com/ISCV44gRuf).

HTML:

```
<div class="rounded rounded-xl w-72 h-32 bg-red-700 relative block overflow-hidden">
    <div class="w-36 h-36 text-red-800 absolute -left-8 -bottom-8">
        <svg fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512"><!-- Font Awesome Free 5.15.3 by @fontawesome  - https://fontawesome.com License - https://fontawesome.com/license/free (Icons: CC BY 4.0, Fonts: SIL OFL 1.1, Code: MIT License) --><path d="M483.55,227.55H462c-50.68,0-76.07-61.27-40.23-97.11L437,115.19A28.44,28.44,0,0,0,396.8,75L381.56,90.22c-35.84,35.83-97.11,10.45-97.11-40.23V28.44a28.45,28.45,0,0,0-56.9,0V50c0,50.68-61.27,76.06-97.11,40.23L115.2,75A28.44,28.44,0,0,0,75,115.19l15.25,15.25c35.84,35.84,10.45,97.11-40.23,97.11H28.45a28.45,28.45,0,1,0,0,56.89H50c50.68,0,76.07,61.28,40.23,97.12L75,396.8A28.45,28.45,0,0,0,115.2,437l15.24-15.25c35.84-35.84,97.11-10.45,97.11,40.23v21.54a28.45,28.45,0,0,0,56.9,0V462c0-50.68,61.27-76.07,97.11-40.23L396.8,437A28.45,28.45,0,0,0,437,396.8l-15.25-15.24c-35.84-35.84-10.45-97.12,40.23-97.12h21.54a28.45,28.45,0,1,0,0-56.89ZM224,272a48,48,0,1,1,48-48A48,48,0,0,1,224,272Zm80,56a24,24,0,1,1,24-24A24,24,0,0,1,304,328Z"/></svg>
    </div>
<div>
```

Tailwind Docs: [Overflow](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/overflow)

Answer (score 0):

Just create one class inside class

```
 .show-inner {
     overflow: hidden;
  }
```

[image]

[Please find solution here](https://play.tailwindcss.com/B6eUtQGHE4?file=css)

Comment: He is using Tailwind, so it's probably better to recommend a Tailwind solution.